# HLS/fMP4 (CMAF) redundant/fallback (Primary/Backup) workflow on Apple Devices is not working

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, failover, redundancy, fmp4

I'm trying to publish my HLS/fMP4 (CMAF) stream to Akamai with Primary/Backup workflow.

When I tested with Shaka player, it works fine: Whenever publishing to Primary entry point stopped, player will properly switch to Backup stream and keep playing back.

However, somehow it does not work on safari on iOS11 nor macOS High Sierra.
I'm wondering if it is a limitation in Apple Devices, or there's compatibility issue in my master playlist.

Here's the sample master playlist file.

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:7
#EXT-X-INDEPENDENT-SEGMENTS

#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="default-p",NAME="audio-eng-p",LANGUAGE="eng",DEFAULT=YES,URI="https://foo.akamaized.net/cmaf/live/123456/FailOverTest/index_bitrate128K.m3u8"
#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID="default-b",NAME="audio-eng-b",LANGUAGE="eng",DEFAULT=NO,URI="https://foo.akamaized.net/cmaf/live/123456-b/FailOverTest/index_bitrate128K.m3u8"

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=928000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="default-p"
https://foo.akamaized.net/cmaf/live/123456/FailOverTest/index_bitrate800K.m3u8
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=928000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.4d401f,mp4a.40.2",AUDIO="default-b"
https://foo.akamaized.net/cmaf/live/123456-b/FailOverTest/index_bitrate800K.m3u8
```

NOTE: for readability, I included only 1 video and audio pair.

Please let me know if you notice something.